# Visual Studio LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file - .obj (COFF) from Flat Assembler

Tags: c, visual-studio, fasm, coff

I am trying to compile somebody's program that is partly written in assembler and partly in C language. The program is available in compiled version, however I need to change it a bit. The source code of the program consists of one .c file and one .asm file.
Without changing anything yet I tried to compile the program in Visual Studio 2017 and Flat Assembler (version 1.73). I compiled the .asm file and Flat Assembler gave me .obj file (unlzws4.obj). Then I created a new empty project in VS and imported .c file and .obj file from FASM.

[image]

Here the problem appears. During the compilation Visual Studio gives me this linking error:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: unlibs4, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>unlibs4.c
1>unlzws4.obj : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x10EE4
1>Done building project "unlibs4.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tried to find out why this error appears, however with no results. The code is supposed to be correct.

unlibs4.c file:

```
// (c) CTPAX-X Team 2018 http://www.CTPAX-X.org/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef GCC32HACK
#include "win32gcc.h"
#endif

#define S4L_REVISION 0x1000
#define S4F_PACKED   1
#define S4F_CRYPTED  2
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    DWORD headsize; /* size of this header with all data */
    DWORD revision; /* MUST be equal to 0x1000 */
    DWORD dnamelen; /* directory names block len */
    DWORD dcounter; /* directory count in block  */
    DWORD fnamelen; /* file names block len */
    DWORD fcounter; /* files counter */
} headinfo;

typedef struct
{
    DWORD floffs; /* looks like first always 1 (.LIB file starts with one zero byte) */
    DWORD pksize; /* packed size */
    DWORD unsize; /* unpacked size (zero if file not packed) */
    DWORD dindex; /* directory name index */
    DWORD xflags; /* flags: 1 - packed; 2 - crypted; */
    DWORD crcsum; /* file CRC (16 bit); can be zero; only for packed files? */
} fileinfo;
#pragma pack(pop)


extern void WINAPI unlzws4(BYTE *undata, DWORD *unsize, BYTE *pkdata, DWORD *pksize);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *dnames, *fnames, *s, *d, name[MAX_PATH];
    fileinfo *list;
    FILE *fl, *f;
    headinfo hi;
    DWORD i, j;
    BYTE *p, *u;
    printf("The Settlers IV .LIB unpacker v1.0\n(c) CTPAX-X Team 2018\nhttp://www.CTPAX-X.org/\n\n");
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: unlibs4 <filename.lib>\n\n");
        return(1);
    }
    fl = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!fl)
    {
        printf("Error: can't open input file.\n\n");
        return(2);
    }
    /* read TOC offs */
    fseek(fl, 0, SEEK_END);
    fseek(fl, ftell(fl) - 4, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&i, 4, 1, fl);
    /* read TOC */
    fseek(fl, i, SEEK_SET);
    memset(&hi, 0, sizeof(hi));
    fread(&hi, sizeof(hi), 1, fl);
    if (hi.revision != S4L_REVISION)
    {
        fclose(fl);
        printf("Error: invalid/unknown input file format.\n\n");
        return(3);
    }
    /* allocate memory */
    dnames = (char *)malloc(hi.dnamelen);
    fnames = (char *)malloc(hi.fnamelen);
    list = (fileinfo *)malloc(hi.fcounter * sizeof(list[0]));
    if (dnames && fnames && list)
    {
        /* read strings */
        fread(dnames, hi.dnamelen, 1, fl);
        fread(fnames, hi.fnamelen, 1, fl);
        /* read file infos */
        fread(list, hi.fcounter, sizeof(list[0]), fl);
        /* create all directories before */
        d = dnames;
        for (i = 0; i < hi.dcounter; i++)
        {
            CreateDirectory(d, NULL);
            d += strlen(d) + 1;
        }
        /* unpack */
        s = fnames;
        for (i = 0; i < hi.fcounter; i++)
        {
            /* find directory name */
            d = dnames;
            j = list[i].dindex;
            while (j > 0)
            {
                d += strlen(d) + 1;
                j--;
            }
            /* merge directory with file */
            sprintf(name, "%s\\%s", d, s);
            /* dump to disk */
            printf("%s\n", name);
            f = fopen(name, "wb");
            if (f)
            {
                p = (BYTE *)malloc(list[i].pksize);
                if (p)
                {
                    fseek(fl, list[i].floffs, SEEK_SET);
                    fread(p, list[i].pksize, 1, fl);
                    if (list[i].xflags & S4F_CRYPTED)
                    {
                        printf("Warning: encrypted file, but decryption not supported - saving as is.\n");
                    }
                    /* decryption not supported, that's why '==' instead of just '&' */
                    if ((list[i].xflags & (S4F_CRYPTED | S4F_PACKED)) == S4F_PACKED)
                    {
                        u = (BYTE *)malloc(list[i].unsize);
                        if (u)
                        {
                            j = list[i].unsize;
                            unlzws4(u, &list[i].unsize, p, &list[i].pksize);
                            free(p);
                            p = u;
                            list[i].pksize = j;
                        }
                    }
                    fwrite(p, list[i].pksize, 1, f);
                    free(p);
                }
                fclose(f);
            }
            /* next filename */
            s += strlen(s) + 1;
        }
        printf("\ndone\n\n");
    }
    if (dnames) { free(dnames); }
    if (fnames) { free(fnames); }
    if (list) { free(list); }
    fclose(fl);
    return(0);
}
```

Beginning of the unlzws4.asm file:

```
; To compile this source code you'll need FASM:
; http://flatassembler.net/
FORMAT COFF

include 'win32ax.inc'

; define section so this can be merged to the code block
section '.text' code

public @startup as '_unlzws4@16'

; some consts
;dword_616478 - start
dword_6167E0 = buf_all + 6167E0h - 616478h
dword_6167E4 = buf_all + 6167E4h - 616478h
dword_616DF8 = buf_all + 616DF8h - 616478h
dword_617060 = buf_all + 617060h - 616478h
dword_617064 = buf_all + 617064h - 616478h

; ###########################################################################

; some startup initialization code
@startup:
  push    esi
  push    edi
  xor     eax, eax
  cld
  ; clear all buffers
  mov     edi, buf_65536
  mov     ecx, 65536 / 4
  rep stosd
  ; ---
  mov     edi, buf_548
  mov     ecx, 548 / 4
  rep     stosd
  ; reinit static buffer since it can be modified due unpacking (sic!)
  mov     esi, dword_616478
  mov     edi, buf_all
  mov     ecx, (3112d + 152d) / 4
  rep     movsd
  ; ---
  pop     edi
  pop     esi
  ; emulate some class structure
  mov     ecx, _buf
  ; jump to the actual unpacking routine
  jmp     @sub_573090

; ###########################################################################

@sub_572450:
var_4           = -4
arg_0           =  4
arg_4           =  8
  push    ecx
  push    ebx
  mov     ebx, [esp+8+arg_0]
  push    ebp
  mov     ebp, [esp+0Ch+arg_4]
  push    esi
  push    edi
  mov     esi, 28h
@loc_572462:

...
```

I don't know much about assembler, I just need to change the C part of the program and compile it as .dll library. I am wondering if the error appears just because of some settings in Visual Studio project. Everything is set to default options.

Comment: https://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=6202 may be relevant.  If not https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/81c26278-3965-4567-8b1a-bb9e98b5f53a/fatal-error-lnk1107-invalid-or-corrupt-file-cannot-read-at-0x168?forum=vcgeneral.  Also the .asm targets win32 - are you compiling the C to Win32 to Win64?

Comment: The first link I saw before. Here I don't need to use extern "C" as it is .c file. The compiled program should be one .exe file without anything else. I tried to compile it for Win32.

Comment: Read the subsequent posts - there is a correction for C code - your extern declaration is correct for C code.  Your problem I think is the use of COFF rather than MSCOFF.

Comment: The program compiles using MinGW and command: gcc unlibs4.c unlzws4.obj -o unlibs4.exe

Answer (score 1):

To link using the Microsoft linker you need to have MSCOFF format object files.  Where you have

```
FORMAT COFF
```

You need:

```
FORMAT MS COFF
```

From https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#2.4.3 :

> **2.4.3 Common Object File Format**
>
> To select Common Object File Format, use format COFF or format MS COFF directive, depending whether you
>   want to create classic (DJGPP) or Microsoft's variant of COFF file.
>   The default code setting for this format is 32-bit. To create the file
>   in Microsoft's COFF format for the x86-64 architecture, use format
>   MS64 COFF setting, in such case long mode code is generated by
>   default.

Comment: Changing FORMAT COFF to FORMAT MS COFF didn't fix the issue. The original compiled program is compiled under Win32.